# Error when using join and join produces error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make groups and make joins with the below tables but I get an

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

error.

Any ideas how to fix?

```
SELECT staffn, job, COUNT(*)"staffcount",  AVG(sal)"AverageSal"
FROM staff, shop
 WHERE  staff.shopno= shop.shopno
 GROUP BY shopno, job;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY shopno`...you need to tell it which shopno field you mean (just like you did in the where clause)

Comment: Because you need to use aliases or table names especially for common columns of tables such as `staff.staffn, staff.job` or `st.staffn, st.job` where `st` is alias for the table `staff`.

Comment: Btw what you have shown is not a proper join. That would be done using `inner join` or `left outer join`, for example. Make sure you study the correct syntax

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper `alias` and your `group by` clause must include all the unaggregated columns as follows:

```
SELECT s.staffn, sh.job, 
       COUNT(*)"staffcount",  
       AVG(s.sal)"AverageSal"
  FROM staff s join shop sh
 WHERE s.shopno= sh.shopn
 Group by s.staffn, sh.job
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to include `staffn` In your select? I would guess that this was unique to a row in `staff` and would make selecting the average (or any other aggregation) `sal` a bit useless (and if you did want to do that, you’d need to include it in the group by). I think you really meant to select the same column in your group by.

Your error is telling you that Oracle doesn’t know where a column should be taken from, multiple row sources in your query could provide it. The complete error message will also make it clear which column this is referring to, but we can already see that at least `shopno` is shared, we can arbitrarily take it from `staff`.

```
SELECT staff.shopno, job, COUNT(*)"staffcount",  AVG(sal)"AverageSal"
FROM staff, shop
 WHERE  staff.shopno= shop.shopno
 GROUP BY staff.shopno, job;
```

Answer (score 0):

In both tables you used, there is at least a field with the same name. You must specify which field used which table.

[for more information](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm#:%7E:text=Cause%3A%20A%20column%20name%20used,its%20table%20name%20when%20referenced.&text=When%20ORA%2D00918%20is%20thrown,which%20has%20been%20ambiguously%20defined.)

Answer (score -1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

In a query that references multiple tables, qualify *all* column references.

You haven't shown the layout of your tables, but you presumably want something like this:

```
SELECT st.staffn, st.job, COUNT(*) as staffcount, 
       AVG(st.sal) as AverageSal
FROM staff st JOIN
     shop sh
     ON st.shopno = sh.shopno
GROUP BY st.staffn, st.job;
```

This assumes that all the columns come from the `staff` table, which seems reasonable enough in the absence of other information.

Comment: I seem to get ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @COLE92 . . . The `SELECT` columns need to be consistent with the `GROUP BY`.  I hadn't realized that those were wrong as well.